# flex 4.6 : How to cache image captured using PersistenceManager

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

Im beginner in Flex mobile application , my issue is the app restart then i used PersistenceManager to solve it, but when i take an image with camera i cannot hold the image if the app restart then how to hold all image captured when user click to save button i think it will be in the imagecaptured method but it doesn't work the app restarted and camera app is opened to take image  method is

```
public function imagecaptured(event:MediaEvent):void
        {
            //submitButton.enabled = false;
            antherImg.label = "please wait to detect your location";
            imagepromise = event.data;
            imgBorder.source = imagepromise.file.url;
            //values to send
            var imgURL:Object = imagepromise.file.url;
            var imgName:Object = imagepromise.relativePath;

            //save Persistence
            var saveManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();            
            saveManager.setProperty("url", imagepromise.file.url);
            saveManager.setProperty("name", imagepromise.relativePath);
        }
```

and when page creation (creationComplete)

```
 public var loadManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();


if(loadManager.load())
            {

                var savedData:Object = saveManager.getProperty("url");
                var savedData:Object = saveManager.getProperty("name");


            }
```

Please help , Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you targeting iOS, Android, or both?  (`MediaPromise.file` does not work on iOS.)  What are the values before and after app restart?

Comment: I am targeting android

Comment: the values are qrcode , images and flags

Comment: Those values don't make much sense for what's going into and coming out of the persistence manager.  E.g., what are `imagepromise.file.url` before, and `saveManager.getProperty("url")` after?  Is your problem with the PersistenceManager, or is there an issue with URLs no longer being valid, or are you not getting the right data in the first place?

Comment: I use imagepromise.file.url before, and saveManager.getProperty("url") after to check if an image is captured then hold it, but it doesn't work and image sometimes lose and app open camera again.
 i will decode image to base64 to send it through web services, if an idea to  hold the bytes of array ?